# Grails ElasticSearch Plugin: Component type mapping

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-plugin

I am using Grails-Elastic-search Plugin(0.0.3.0).

I have 2 domain entities:- A and B.
Entity B is mapped as a component in entity A.
Example:-

```
class A {
   static searchable = {
       B component: true
   }
}
```

Changes made to entity B are reflected in Elastic-search for index B but changes are not reflected in entity A.

Do we need to re-index entity A? If so is this a bug in the Plugin or as per the design?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that [this](https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/elasticsearch/AuditEventListener.groovy#L136) is the code relevant to your question.

Per the documentation, B is actually stored as a part of A's indexed document. Since A is the root entity in this case, and A itself has not been updated, you can see that A will not be re-indexed. Not sure if this is "by design", or a shortcoming, but I can tell you that it is right there in the code.

For the lazy:

```
void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    def entity = getEventEntity(event)
    if (!entity) {
        logger.warn('Received a PostUpdateEvent with no entity')
        return
    }
    if (elasticSearchContextHolder.isRootClass(entity.class)) {
        pushToIndex(entity)
    }
}
```